# Understanding Stromberg's Proof about Real Exponents

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponentiation

On pages 238-239 of his book *An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis* Stromberg gives a proof of the following Theorem:

[image]
[image]

I understand all the proof except for the statement (near the end) that we can write any $z \in C$ as $z=a^b e^{2\pi i t}$ for some $0\leq t <1$.

I can only show that it holds for some $-1/2<t\leq1/2$. Can you help me figure out why this is the case?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: $e^{2\pi it}$ has period $1$ so the image of $-1/2<t\leq1/2$ is the same as the image of $0<s \le 1$ by the substitution $s=t+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Right! You mean shifting the segment $(-1/2,0]$ by $1$ unit to the right (keeping the same image under $e^{2\pi i t}$) while keeping the segment $(0,1/2]$?

Comment: yes - (technically you reparametrize) - but in this problem you only need that the images are the same, so you do not really care about parametrization (in other words the fractional part can be taken in $[0,1)$ or $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ while indeed the parametrization is by pieces depending on whether you are in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ or not)

Comment: @Conrad Great thank you so much I will add an answer.

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Conrad the periodicity of $e^{2\pi i t}$ is $1$ so if  $t\in (-1/2,0)$ then I can simply take $t'=t+1 \in (1/2,1)$.